# What is the difference in nuance between 間違う and 間違える?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I've heard from a Japanese native speaker friend of mine that both 間違う and 間違える are correct usage, but he wasn't able to explain the difference in nuance between them. Is there a difference, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When we say that someone makes a mistake about something, we can use both 間違う and 間違える and there is no difference in meaning or nuance.  For example, 計算を間違えた and 計算を間違った mean the same thing.

[*Added remark*: As repecmps pointed out in a comment, some people consider this usage of 間違う as incorrect.  [Someone states](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1214351857) that this usage of 間違う was originally incorrect, but I do not know if this statement is true or not.]

When we say that something is in a wrong state, we can only use 間違う.  Examples from Daijisen with my English translations:

> ○ この[手紙]{てがみ}は[住所]{じゅうしょ}が[間違]{まちが}っている。 This letter has an incorrect address on it.
> × この手紙は住所が間違えている。

> ○ [間違]{まちが}った[考]{かんが}え[方]{かた}  a wrong way of thinking
> × 間違えた考え方

([○ denotes correct examples and × denotes incorrect examples](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169/should-we-have-a-standard-notation-for-example-sentences).)

Comment: I'm sorry but 計算を間違った is incorrect (although probably widely used). See my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I think it has more to do with transitive v. intransitive.  // You wouldn't say 間違えた考え方 unless you said something like 誰かさんが間違えた考え方について～ something something (otherwise you're implying its your way of thinking that's wrong) - but it's not incorrect, only on its own. Along the same lines you wouldn't say 誰かが間違った考え方.

Comment: @repecmps: Are you claiming that the dictionary I linked to is incorrect?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito: It's funny how you feel hurt whenever I say something. I tried not to sound rude though. I'm claiming "計算を間違った" is not grammatically correct. (I thought my comment was clear). The Daijisen examples are correct.

Comment: @repecmps: Your comments are contradictory.  Daijisen states that 間違う can be used in the same way as 間違える, you claim that it cannot be, and you also claim that Daijisen is correct.  You can believe that 間違う cannot be used as a transitive verb as much as you want, but you are simply wrong.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1214351857"「字を間違う」というのはまちがい、なのですが、
「間違える」の誤用が一般化して、現在は辞書にも「間違う」が
「間違える、の新しい言い方」と定義され、他動詞としても認められています。"

Comment: @repecmps: Thanks for the link.  By the way, have you understood that your comments were contradictory?

Comment: I searched but I cannot find "計算を間違った" in the dictionary link.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/659/discussion-between-repecmps-and-tsuyoshi-ito)

Comment: im in keio learning the language right now and ive already asked 2 japanese teachers and other friends this same question. there's no transitive/intransitive structure in regards to them. they are one and the same except in cases like potential form, you might want to use one over the other for clarity. (e.g: potential form, you want may want to say 間違えられる instead since the other one will turn into 間違える). that being said, i don't think it hurts to think of one as transitive and the other as intransitive either

Answer (score 17):

The answer is a simple point of grammar:

間違う is an [intransitive verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_verb). With no direct object, the particle を cannot be used.

ー＞私が間違っている

間違える is a [transitive verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb), with a direct object (use of を possible as well as other particles)

ー＞道を間違えた

According to the [chat discussion with Tsuyoshi](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/659) I understand that recent dictionaries allow the use of 間違う with a direct object, making all his examples correct.

More details in [this link](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1214351857).

But as a grammar enthusiast, I think that using the rule above, you will always be correct.

Comment: Prescriptivism/descriptivism aside, it's arguably *more useful* to attempt to maintain the regularity of transitive/intransitive verb forms in Japanese; so in that case, it would *behoove* us to promote this ;) (On the other hand, the regularity argument is used by linguistic analysts to explain the popularity of ら抜き, so beware the utilitarian :)