# おしまい {oshimai} vs おわり {owari}

Tags: word-choice, nuances

Are there any differences between using おしまい {oshimai} and おわり {owari} to mean "the end" (both with neutral and negative connotations)? Are they always interchangeable?

E.g:

> テスト失敗したらおわりだぜ。
>
> テスト失敗したらおしまいだぜ。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's really much difference in meaning or connotation, although おしまい sounds more formal to me, probably because it has the honorific お attached. OTOH, I've never seen お仕舞い at the end of a movie, so maybe there are differences in customary usage. {EDIT: The following is inaccurate: 終わる is also used transitively} One difference is that you can "おしまいにする" something, whereas you can't "おわりにする" things, because of the transitive/intransitive pairing 終える/終わる.(END EDIT, see comments)

In your example sentences (incidentally, you need to stick a "に" in them), I don't think there's a dime's worth of difference between the two. They both mean "I'm done for, it's all over, the jig is up, put a fork in me, Goodnight Irene."

Comment: From the kanji used in お仕舞い, I thought the word has some root in Noh theater so maybe it was (or is probably still) used to at the end of a play. Am I right?

Comment: It appears to have associations with noh, but with a different meaning:  http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BB%95%E8%88%9E  - Whether お仕舞い was used as a curtain-closer, I don't know. That sounds like a question for @Matt 's erudite consideration.

Comment: I do not find anything wrong with the expression 終わりにする.

Comment: In fact, [終わる](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E7%B5%82%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=102847800000) is used also in the form of ～を終わる.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito - Just checked this, and you are correct.　I should have checked myself beforehand: 大辞線 gives 終える　as a synonym.(恥) Thanks for the info; I'll edit the post for accuracy. This seems very odd, though. Are there other transitive/intransitive pairs that you can think of where this occurs?

Comment: The pair [間違う/間違える](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1598/what-is-the-difference-in-nuance-between-and) comes to my mind.  Some people claim that using 間違う as a transitive verb is an error (pun unavoidable), but at least dictionaries state that 間違う can be used as a synonym for 間違える.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito - 助かりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

"Oshimai" can be formal, but it is also used with small children. I would translate it as something like "We're done with that now" or "We're moving on"

"Owari" has more of a feeling of finality, as in "We won't be coming back to this again" or "That time has passed."

I agree with previous comments on the grammar of it all, but the connontation is important as well.

Source: I teach K-12 in Japan

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, I think that おしまい is mostly used to close an event or a ceremony, something that has been willingly started.  So your second sentence sounds weird to me.

On the other hand, I think that おわり is not something you control.  Your sentence says it's over, not that you stopped it.

Comment: But I've heard もうおしまいだ being uttered by characters in many anime and dramas I've watched ..

Comment: @Lukman: in what respect does it contradict what I wrote?

Comment: "... something that has been willingly started. So your second sentence sounds weird to me." But I've heard もうおしまいだ being uttered by characters in many anime and dramas I've watched ..

Comment: @Lukman: I reiterate. (1) Your example is *not* もうおしまいだ, and (2), what I believe that your characters could say in the context of someone wanting to apply for a banquet, to say that the application period has now finished; in this case, there is still no contradiction.  I never said that "おしまい" couldn't be heard in mangas or real life (since after all, it's a real word), I said that your example sounded weird to me.

Comment: I believe all the characters that I heard saying おしまいだ (with もう or not is irrelevant) meant to say "it's over for me" not with reference to banquet, applications or what not. p/s: just in case you think I'm the one who downvoted this answer, please look at my profile to see that I still maintain my 0-downvote record ;)